# Swift Hide Nav Bar on One Page

Tags: swift

I have an app that opens to the main scene and checks for a token to see if the user is logged in. If they are all is good and it loads. If not it redirects them to a login screen, they login and then it pushes them back to the main screen.

I'm trying to hide the nav bar just on the login page which loads if there's no token. I've found many instances of code that work, like this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = true
```

that hide it however they also hide the nav bar on the first instance of the main page. How can I avoid this?

EDIT: I've tried the following and still no luck! Same result of the navbar hiding on the login screen but hidden when the user is first moved to the main scene. Any other move to the main screen shows the navbar. How is this happening??

Attempt 1:

```
ON LOGIN PAGE

In viewDidLoad() -> self.navigationController!.navigationBar.hidden = true


ON MAIN PAGE

In viewDidLoad() -> self.navigationController!.navigationBar.hidden = false
```

Attempt 2

```
ON LOGIN PAGE

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController!.navigationBarHidden = true
}

ON MAIN PAGE

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController!.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```

Attempt 3

```
ON LOGIN PAGE

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController!.navigationBarHidden = true
}

ON MAIN PAGE

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController!.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```

Could it have something to do with the way I'm moving to the main page after the user logs in?

```
ON LOGIN PAGE:
let secondViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FriendsTableViewController") as! UITableViewController
//go to the main page
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

in viewWillDissapear you can set `self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden` to false again.

Comment: Same thing for both of these. I now have viewWillAppear ...navigationBar.Hidder = true in the login screen and the bar is hidden. The first time the main scene loads there's no navbar (even with the viewWillDissappear to false again). When I move away from that screen and back though it shows up. Does it matter that this is a tableviewcontroller??

Answer (score 0):

Set it to hidden in **viewDidAppear**. I had to use something like this in my application and it worked.

```
Override func viewWillAppear(){     Self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        /** remove the shadow image (border) altogether from nav bar **/
    for parent in self.navigationController!.navigationBar.subviews {
        for childView in parent.subviews {
            if(childView is UIImageView) {
                childView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
```

}